# TextInputEditText does not occupy the height and weight of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml

I want the TextInputEditText to occupy the whole space of its parent TextInputLayout but it seems that the TextInputEditText is adjusted a little below of TextInputLayout (as there is a white space at top of it from the parent).

this is the code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tvPassword"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/lightBlack"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="3dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

this is TextInputLayout when I select it
[TextInputLayout selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHfP6.png)

and this is TextInputEditText
[TextInputEditText selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJCKm.png)

I tried to set the padding of TextInputLayout to 0dp but it does not solve it.

I want TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText to look like this:
(image from figma)
[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMaGK.png)